# WKID (Well Known ID) for national projection for ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, web-service, rest, arcgis-rest-api

I have to use my national projection system which does not have corresponding WKID listed for ArcGIS REST API.   Without it I am unable to use this projection system for my web application.  Any pointers which can help me out to use my data in its native projection format?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have not stated what version of ArcGIS Server you are running.
If you are on 9.3.1 your stuck with the WKIDs that REST supports:

- [Projected](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/pcs.html)
- [Geographic](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/gcs.html)

The other option (which I have done before) is submit a WKID request to Esri Support.
For me, we sent them the projection file and they created a NIM, and at the next version it was included.  I know other's have not had as much luck as I did though.

I did see some [other people](http://blogs.esri.com/Info/blogs/arcgisexplorerblog/archive/2010/01/20/changing-the-central-meridian-via-the-sdk.aspx) implement client-side code or add-ons to try and transform the images after Server has dished it up in a supported WKID - not an easy option.

**However**, if you are running **10**, REST now supports [Well Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (WKT)

> Well-known text is now supported as a
>   valid format for specifying coordinate
>   systems. Previously, coordinate
>   systems could only be specified in the
>   REST API through a numerical ID. Now
>   you can use a specially formatted text
>   string to denote the coordinate
>   system, allowing for customized
>   properties such as central meridian
>   and standard parallels.

Just watch out for long URL lengths with GET requests in your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are some references for GIS cordinate systems IDs,which has assigned by their creators like EPSG and you can refer to them.And also ArcGIS lets you define your custom spatial coordinate system.did you try to define your custome spatial coordinate system in ArcCatalog or ArcMap?

Comment: That's not what the poster asked, is it. He wants to know how to map a WKID used in AGS REST API to a coordinate system for those systems which are not directly listed/supported.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had ArcGIS Server, couldn't you publish a map service using your custom projection and then view on the REST service endpoint page the spatial reference?

Answer (score 0):

Each coordinate system is defined by a well-known ID (WKID) or a definition string (WKT, Well Known Text). Before ArcGIS Server 10.0, the ArcGIS Server REST API only supported well-known IDs (not definition strings), but as of ArcGIS Server 10.0 both are supported. For a complete list of supported well-known IDs and their corresponding definition strings, see links below.
[Geographic Co-ordinates Systems Listing](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/gcs.htm)

[Project Co-ordinates Systems Listing](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/pcs.htm)

So for mapping, you will have to do it for yourself.
make property file, in which you can have the mapping. with complete, WKT.
and whenever you need to pass CRS to the ESRI API, always pass the WKT, not WKID. Because There are chances, that wkid is not uderstood within ESRI API, but, internally, ESRI API, can understand the WKT.

hope this will help you.
-- Ravindra Shekhawat